# Adding a link in addto-links

Tags: magento-1.8

What is the standard procedure or the best solution to add a new link to the `product.info.addto` block.

Currently I have modified the following file
`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml` by adding an extra `<li>` to the existing link.

What I am worried is whether this will affect future upgrades and if so, what could be the solution.

**EDITED**
I need to add a link "Add to Favorites" near "Add to Wishlist" and "Add to Compare".

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? What link are you trying to add?

Comment: @sr_magento, Have modified my question.

Comment: You did a right way..You edited one of the theme file only. So no need to worry about future upgrade ..But you need to move that file to your own theme folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never modify core code** instead copy it to your active theme:

```
copy app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/default/ACTIVE_TEMPLATE/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml
```

This will prevent any future upgrades from over writing your work and trying to hunt down changes you've made.

You can either implement the *Add to Favorites* by doing as you suggested with a copy of addto.phtml in your active theme.

or

Modify **view.phtml** and **list.phtml** and customize with CSS.

Comment: Does `ACTIVE_TEMPLATE` refers to a specific template like `default/modern`? If so will it be viewable even when the admin changes the theme of the store to something else. As I am new I cant catch you quickly.

Comment: Correct! And no, the changes will only be reflected in the theme you modify. The rule is to never modify core code, so anything under /base/ should be copied to the active theme you intend on using. Again, this prevents files from being over written when you upgrade magento in the future. Kindly accept this as the answer and let us know if you have any other questions. Thank you, SR

Comment: So there is no way to add a template code outside base/default that will be available for all themes. Am I right?